# function for which substitution equals expression

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for the function $f(x)$ for which $x=\frac{L}{2}$ results in $\frac{PL^3}{48EI}$.

I also know that $f(0) = 0$, $f(L)=0$ and $\frac{df}{dx}_{@ x = \frac{L}{2}}=0$

Do we have enough information to solve this function? Is there a systematic way to determine it and generalize to other similar functions?

Comment: The simplest function satisfying the conditions is a parabola. It is not the only one...

Comment: Is this part of a structural analysis question?

Comment: Yes. It is deflection for a beam with point load at midspan.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you meant $dL/dx$ at $x=L/2$  is 0 (rather than du/dx).
No, there is not enough information.
For every function $g$ defined on $[0,1]$ satisfying $g(0)=0, g(1)=1$, you can build an appropriate $f$:
$f(x) = (PL^3/48EI)*[1-g((2x/L-1)^2)]$

Note $g$ also has to be right differentiable at $0$, so that $df/dx$ at $x=L/2$  is 0.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Visit this page in order to learn mathjax : http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\frac{df}{dx}$. Please see correction in original post